nvim yank reg keymapping customized
I am trying to simplify an operations yank to "+ reg.
default：In visual mode "+y
I'd go: <leader>y
I have set in my keymap.lua
keymap.set("i","<leader>y","\"+y")

but it doesn't work.
I have read the manual for keymap, but it is too heavy.

If you place "i" as the first argument in the keymap, it means you want to set a keybinding for insert mode, "v" for visual mode, and "n" for normal mode. You can also make keymap availabe in multiple modes, for example:

vim.keymap.set({"n", "i", "v" }...
vim.keymap.set({"n", "i" }...
vim.keymap.set("n", ...

So if you want to remap yanking try to do it in visual mode
Paste command example:
vim.keymap.set("n", '<C-v>', '"+p', { noremap = true, silent = true })
Copy command example:
vim.keymap.set("v", "<C-c>", '"+y', { noremap = true, silent = true })

This is the standard answer.
